# i dont undestand why that error with my function

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

Missing type arguments for generic function 'showDialog'.
Try adding an explicit type, or remove implicit-dynamic from your analysis options file.

```
void displayDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadiusDirectional.circular(10)),
          elevation: 5,
          title: const Text('Alert'),
          content: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: const [
              Text('Jhonny la gente estwa muy loca'),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              FlutterLogo(
                size: 150,
              )
            ],
          ),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: const Text('Cancelar'),
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue in your code. you can try this.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: PopUpTest());
  }
}

class PopUpTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const PopUpTest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PopUpTest> createState() => _PopUpTestState();
}

class _PopUpTestState extends State<PopUpTest> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                displayDialog(context);
              },
              child: const Text("Open pop up"),
              color: Colors.blue,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void displayDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadiusDirectional.circular(10)),
          elevation: 5,
          title: const Text('Alert'),
          content: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: const [
              Text('Jhonny la gente estwa muy loca'),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              FlutterLogo(
                size: 150,
              )
            ],
          ),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: const Text('Cancelar'),
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image: preview]